# iOS Custom .xib view button tap detect in view controller (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, xib

So I am using a custom View (.xib) which contains couple of objects: `UIImage` view & `UIButton`. The custom view in contained and used in View controller `UIView` , however I can't seem to figure out how to detect if the button(from .xib) is tapped and launch a function in the view controller. Any suggestions?

I can However add `UITap` gesture to the entire `Viewcontroller` UIView, however Thats not what i need.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
@IBAction func calculateTapped(sender : AnyObject) {

     //You can get action here
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand your answer

Comment: Did you set UIControlEventTouchUpInside..

A touch-up event in the control where the finger is inside the bounds of the control.

Comment: I added the following code in view controller:                                                                                                                                                                                                      var View = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView",
            owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? CustomView
        
        View?.thisImageButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

Comment: try using above method

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 
    Link Your all button to to xib cocoa class

`class DialogHandler: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var acceptBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var closeBtn: UIButton!
}`

step 2

```
  Add Below code in viewDidLoad() 

if let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DialogDemo", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? DialogHandler {
        dialogView = customView
        customView.acceptBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.acceptBtnPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)           
    }
```

step 3

Create Function for Button that can handle your click event

```
 @objc func acceptBtnPressed (sender:UIButton) { print("Button Pressed") }
```